# how to use single parameter and multiple parameter send in url in single file in php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want 2 different links in php using .htaccess like in one single file. I want to send 2 type of parameters like

```
http://localhost/new_project/new-signup.php?id=1;
```

and also in other parameters like

```
http://localhost/new_project/new-signup.php?id=1&mode=delete;
```

I want use modes in this files
please give me best solution thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Create a .htaccess file with following code and place it in the root folder of your project.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new-signup/([0-9]+)/([^/]([a-zA-Z]+))?$ new-signup.php?id=$1&mode=$2 [L]
```

Comment: now tell me how to get these parametes like $_request['id']  ??

Comment: Like you get GET parameters `$_GET['id']`